# Cannot get property 'show' on null object in grails

Tags: exception, grails, groovy, nullpointerexception, nul

I am getting:

> Cannot get property 'show' on null object  in my grails project

Here is my code

```
package com.djamware

class TestController {

    EmployeeService employeeService
 
    def secondaryDataSourceTemplate

    def mainDataSourceTemplate
 
    def testService
    static allowedMethods = [save: "POST", update: "PUT", delete: "DELETE"]

    def index() {
        render  testService.show
    }

     def show() {
 
         Employee employee=new Employee();
         employee.setName("Gaurav chauhan")
         employee.setEmail("chauhankgaurav97@gmail.com")
         employee.setPosition("Java Devloper")
         employee.setSalary(new Double(15000.0))
         String sqlQuery = "SELECT name FROM Employee";
         def counti=new Integer(1);
         try {
            def result = secondaryDataSourceTemplate.queryForList(sqlQuery)
    
            println "result of Query is =====>"+result.name
            println "Size of Result ========> "+result.size();
            counti=result.size();
    
         }
    
         catch (Exception e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
             counti=new Integer(10);
         }
         employeeService.save(employee)
         render  counti;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a bean in your application context named `testService`?

Answer (score -1):

Try including into your static methods the definition for `show`

```
static allowedMethods = [show: "GET", save: "POST", update: "PUT", delete: "DELETE"]
```

Comment: the value of `allowedMethods` will not have any impact on the error mentioned in the questionl

Comment: FYI... The effect of making the change you suggested is that the system will generate a 405 if any HTTP verb other than GET is used when accessing the `show` action in that controller.

Comment: I'm sorry I was on my cellphone, now I see it clearly, your error is on the line

`render  testService.show`

You need to verify that you have declared a service or bean called `testService`, Grails will look for that instance and inject if a class called `TestService` exists, otherwise will look bean definition.

One more thing, you need to check if `show` is a property on `testService` or a method, if is a property then is ok if not you have to change for `testService.show()`

Comment: "One more thing, you need to check if show is a property on testService or a method, if is a property then is ok if not you have to change for testService.show()" - The issue doesn't appear to be related to `show` being a property or a method.  The issue appears to be that `testService` is `null`.

Comment: Look at your service layer for a class called `TestService` then it doesn't exist then that's why is not injected.

Remember that grails work, convention over configuration, so as far as you follow the conventions, should detect your service.

Comment: "Look at your service layer for a class called TestService then it doesn't exist then that's why is not injected." - Right.  I am quite familiar with how Grails works.  I was addressing the potentially misleading information in your answer and in subsequent comments.  There is no reason to believe this problem has anything to do with `allowedMethods` or with confusing a property name with a method name.  I am sorry if I have confused the issue further.

Comment: Thanks to all of you.after reach office I wil try your solutions and will update you

Comment: Thanks Joxebus  and Jeff Scott Brown.My issue has been resolved... TestService   was not existed properly that's by error was coming